# How to find out next available number

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL table I have field called sequence where I have values like 
1 , 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 some of the sequence number are skiped due to deleted records. How do I find out next available number from given number. let's say if I need next number from 3 , how do I get number 5 as my next number in sequence not the 4.

Comment: mysql auto_increments don't recycle numbers. you shouldn't have to do anything to get the "next" number. mysql will calculate/use it for you the next time you insert a record. If you mean "given record 3, what's the next higher id", then `select * from yourtable where id>3 order by id asc limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the next ID after 3 that appears in your table, you should do

```
SELECT id FROM thetable WHERE id>3 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

This just considers IDs that are greater than 3, in ascending order, and then takes the first one on that list. If it returns you one result, then that's the next one used in the table; if it doesn't return a result at all, then the ID you gave it was already the highest one in the table (or, strictly speaking, at least as high as the highest one in the table).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general expression that works to get the next available number, then you can use an aggregation query:

```
select coalesce(max(id), maxid + 1) as NextAvailableId
from table t cross join
     (select max(id) as maxid from table t) x
where id > 3;
```

Or, if you don't like the `cross join`, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select coalesce(max(case when id > 3 then id end), max(id)) as NextAvailableId
from table t;
```